The problem with the adaptive slider in pure JavaScript
I needed a slider in pure JavaScript and I used the code below, but modified it for my project. If something is named strangely, then don't pay attention to it, I cut it out of my project and simplified it. The problem is that when dragging objects on the computer, everything works fine. But on the phone or in adaptive layout mode, objects move incorrectly. I've used different ways to initialize tapping on the phone and this is the simplest of them, but they all work the same way.
I checked the events of dragging and finding the inside of the container, but it didn't help me.


const containerMass = 5;
const mouseMass = 10;

let imageHasLoaded = false;

let mouseX = 0;
let prevMouseX = 0;
let mouseXOnDown = null;
let isMouseDown = false;

let containerPosition = 0;
let mouseVelocity = 0;
let containerVelocity = 0;

let imagesElement = null;

const createBeltScroller = (container, images) => {
  imageHasLoaded = true;
  const beltDOMItems = images.map((image, index) => {
    const element = document.createElement("div");
    element.classList.add("item");
    const elementDiv = document.createElement("div");
    elementDiv.style.height = "200px";
    elementDiv.style.width = "200px";
    elementDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
    elementDiv.innerHTML = image
    element.appendChild(elementDiv);
    return element;
  });
  imagesElement = beltDOMItems.map((element) => element);
  beltDOMItems.forEach((beltDOMItem) => {
    container.appendChild(beltDOMItem);
  });
};
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

createBeltScroller(container, ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]);

// Mouse event handlers
const onMouseUpdate = (event) => {
  mouseX = event.pageX;
}; // Mouse movement
const onMouseDown = () => {
  isMouseDown = true;
}; // Mouse button press
const onMouseUp = () => {
  isMouseDown = false;
}; // Mouse button release

// Add pointer event listeners
document.addEventListener("pointermove", onMouseUpdate, false);
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("pointerdown", onMouseDown);
document.addEventListener("pointerup", onMouseUp);

const calculateMouseMomentum = () => {
  if (isMouseDown) {
    if (mouseXOnDown == null) {
      mouseXOnDown = mouseX;
      containerVelocity = 0;
    }
    const distance = mouseX - mouseXOnDown;
    mouseVelocity = mouseX - prevMouseX;
  } else {
    if (mouseXOnDown != null) {
      containerVelocity =
        ((2 * mouseMass) / (mouseMass + containerMass)) * mouseVelocity +
        ((containerMass - mouseMass) / (mouseMass + containerMass)) *
        containerVelocity;

      const maxVelocity = 60;

      if (containerVelocity > maxVelocity) {
        containerVelocity = maxVelocity;
      } else if (containerVelocity < -maxVelocity) {
        containerVelocity = -maxVelocity;
      }

      mouseXOnDown = null;
      mouseVelocity = 0;
    }
  }

  prevMouseX = mouseX;
};

const updateContainer = () => {
  const boundRight = -container.offsetWidth + window.innerWidth - 85;

  const isOutBound =
    containerPosition > 0 || containerPosition < boundRight;

  if (!isMouseDown) {
    const mu = 0.04;
    const g = 10;
    const flictionForce = containerMass * g * mu;
    const flictionA = flictionForce / containerMass;

    if (containerVelocity > 0) {
      containerVelocity -= flictionA;
      if (containerVelocity < 0) {
        containerVelocity = 0;
      }
    } else if (containerVelocity < 0) {
      containerVelocity += flictionA;
      if (containerVelocity > 0) {
        containerVelocity = 0;
      }
    }

    if (isOutBound) {
      const k = 0.01;
      const restLength = containerPosition > 0 ? 0 : boundRight;
      const currentLength = containerPosition;
      const dragForce = 1 * k * (restLength - currentLength);

      const dragForceA = dragForce / containerMass;
      containerVelocity += dragForce;

      const nextPosition = containerPosition + containerVelocity;

      if (containerPosition < boundRight && nextPosition > boundRight) {
        containerVelocity = 0;
        containerPosition = boundRight;
      } else if (containerPosition > 0 && nextPosition < 0) {
        containerVelocity = 0;
        containerPosition = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  containerPosition = containerPosition + containerVelocity + (isOutBound ? mouseVelocity / 2 : mouseVelocity);
  container.style.transform = `translate(${containerPosition}px)`;
};

const loop = () => {
  calculateMouseMomentum();
  updateContainer();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    loop();
  });
};

loop();
.container {
  height: fit-content;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  touch-action: pan-y;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: grab;
  margin: 2% 0;
  font-size: 150px;
}

.item {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding-left: 4.43vw;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
<div id="container" class="container"></div>




I partially found the problem. It consists in 'mouseVelocity', on computer markup it is calculated gradually and evenly, and mouseX and prevMouseX differ from each other by units of pixels. And in mobile mode, 'mouseX' and 'prevMouseX' differ very much at the moment of pressing, which is why the shift gap occurs. BUT THE PROBLEM HAS NOT BEEN SOLVED YET.

I was right. I solved this problem, now the slider is spinning normally on the phone. I don't need solutions.

Maybe it is because of
Mouse Events: Mobile devices primarily use touch events rather than mouse events. While some browsers support mapping touch events to mouse events, it's generally recommended to use touch events directly for better compatibility. You may need to handle touch events (touchstart, touchmove, touchend) in addition to or instead of mouse events.

I've already used them, they work the same way as pointer events. Only the touchstart, touchmove, touchend, and touchcancel events take up more space in the code.
